# Running two VBA procedures in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Can someone tell me how to combine and run both of these in the same Excel worksheet? Please be specific since I am a neophyte at coding!! Thanks

This procedure:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim DateStr As String

On Error GoTo EndMacro
If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
With Target
If .HasFormula = False Then
    Select Case Len(.Formula)
        Case 4 ' e.g., 9298 = 2-Sep-1998
            DateStr = Left(.Formula, 1) & "/" & _ 
            Mid(.Formula, 2, 1) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 2)
        Case 5 ' e.g., 11298 = 12-Jan-1998 NOT 2-Nov-1998
            DateStr = Left(.Formula, 1) & "/" & _ 
                Mid(.Formula, 2, 2) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 2)
        Case 6 ' e.g., 090298 = 2-Sep-1998
            DateStr = Left(.Formula, 2) & "/" & _ 
                Mid(.Formula, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 2)
        Case 7 ' e.g., 1231998 = 23-Jan-1998 NOT 3-Dec-1998
            DateStr = Left(.Formula, 1) & "/" & _ 
                Mid(.Formula, 2, 2) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 4)
        Case 8 ' e.g., 09021998 = 2-Sep-1998
            DateStr = Left(.Formula, 2) & "/" & _ 
                Mid(.Formula, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(.Formula, 4)
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 0
    End Select
    .Formula = DateValue(DateStr)
End If

End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
EndMacro:
MsgBox "You did not enter a valid date."
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

and this procedure:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim TimeStr As String

On Error GoTo EndMacro
If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
With Target
If .HasFormula = False Then
    Select Case Len(.Value)
        Case 1 ' e.g., 1 = 00:01 AM
            TimeStr = "00:0" & .Value
        Case 2 ' e.g., 12 = 00:12 AM
            TimeStr = "00:" & .Value
        Case 3 ' e.g., 735 = 7:35 AM
            TimeStr = Left(.Value, 1) & ":" & _
            Right(.Value, 2)
        Case 4 ' e.g., 1234 = 12:34
            TimeStr = Left(.Value, 2) & ":" & _
            Right(.Value, 2)
        Case 5 ' e.g., 12345 = 1:23:45 NOT 12:03:45
            TimeStr = Left(.Value, 1) & ":" & _
            Mid(.Value, 2, 2) & ":" & Right(.Value, 2)
        Case 6 ' e.g., 123456 = 12:34:56
            TimeStr = Left(.Value, 2) & ":" & _
            Mid(.Value, 3, 2) & ":" & Right(.Value, 2)
        Case Else
            Err.Raise 0
    End Select
    .Value = TimeValue(TimeStr)
End If
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
EndMacro:
MsgBox "You did not enter a valid time"
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't / shouldn't have two functions with the identical name and event. Pick to use one, run one method, followed by the other

Comment: So in my example what are the names and events that I need to change?  I know this is a painfully basic question!

Comment: The name is the string following "Private Sub ".

Comment: Ok.... can someone tell me exactly what changes to make in the coding so both procedures will run.  I can do one or the other but I can't figure out how to get both of them to execute.

Comment: Do you see how both start with **Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)**? **Worksheet_Change** is the name of both events. The name **Worksheet_Change** is unique in Excel to trigger whenever a worksheet changes (It is an **event**). You can't have two events with the same name so leave one as is, rename the second to whatever you desire, and call the renamed one from the one you didn't change.

Comment: FYI, I am not going to literally type what you need. You need to understand what you are doing and find a solution on your own. This community is here to help with specific questions but we aren't here to write code for you.

Comment: That's fair.  If I change the name of the event to anything except Worksheet_Change the procedure doesn't execute.  I can run either Function alone but I am having trouble understanding how do both within the same VBA function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute one sub from the initial one. You can't / shouldn't have two subs / functions with the same name. To run both subs you have shown above whenever a change occurs on a worksheet use the following method:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'Do stuff
Call Peanut_butter()
End Sub

Private Sub Peanut_butter
'Do other stuff

End Sub
```

In this example Worksheet_Change is triggered first, runs whatever code you want, and then lastly executes the sub named Peanut_Butter.